# c# click onces to choose either one of dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

i want to have a another if else statement for my button when first click it will either select imagefile(shuffled01) or text(shuffled02). but how do i implement the codes? any experts! thanks!!! 
i am using two dictionary for my both shuffled.

```
  switch (iNumberOfButtonClick)
          {
              case 1:
                  iButton1 = Convert.ToInt32(button.Name.Substring(1));
                  btn1 = button;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  iButton2 = Convert.ToInt32(button.Name.Substring(1));
                  btn2 = button;
                  break;
              //case 3:
              //    dbutton1 = (b1.Name);
          }




          if (iNumberOfButtonClick.Equals(1))
          {
              {


                var  imageFile = shuffled01[iButton1];
                  ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                  BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

                  bitmap.BeginInit();
                  bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\istellar 22-10-13\iStellarMobile\iStellarMobile\" + imageFile.ToString().Substring(1), UriKind.Absolute);
                  bitmap.EndInit();
                  brush.ImageSource = bitmap;
                  btn1.Background = brush;

                  var text = shuffled02[iButton2];
                  ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
                  BitmapImage bitmap1 = new BitmapImage();

                  bitmap1.BeginInit();
                  bitmap1.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\istellar 22-10-13\iStellarMobile\iStellarMobile\" + text.ToString().Substring(1), UriKind.Absolute);
                  bitmap1.EndInit();
                  brush1.ImageSource = bitmap1;
                  btn2.Background = brush1;


              }

              iNumberOfButtonClick++;
          }
```

Comment: not clear on what you require

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you correctly try the following, but please note, I disagree with your approach above. This is much better solved (IMO) by WPF using a style  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Changing-a-WPF-Button-212386c6 (and probably converters). Also note I really don't like the `_numClicks` approach, try an enum to label the button states.

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="Btn1" Click="OnBtnClick" Width="30" Height="20" />
        <Button Name="Btn2" Click="OnBtnClick" Width="30" Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    private int _numClicks = 0;
    // key = button-name, value = image file name
    private Dictionary<string, string> shuffled01 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ...
    shuffled01.Add(Btn1.Name, "file1");
    shuffled01.Add(Btn2.Name, "file2");

    private void OnBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _numClicks = ++_numClicks % 3; // replace 3 with the number of cases you require
        switch (_numClicks)
        {
            default:
            case 0:
                Btn1.Background = Brushes.Bisque;
                Btn2.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                var imageFileName = shuffled01[Btn1.Name];
                // blah
                break;
            case 1:
                Btn1.Background = Brushes.Chartreuse;
                Btn2.Background = Brushes.Cornsilk;
                // blah
                break;
            case 2:
                // blah
                break;
        }
    }
```